what is best for predicting item demand with irregular time series data?
I'm working on a supervised machine learning project to predict future demand for pharmacy items. My objective is to forecast the next day, week, and month demand for a specific item based on historical sales data. However, I'm facing challenges due to the irregular nature of the time series data, and I would like advice on the best approach to handle this.
Dataset Details:

Start date: 2023-05-02
End date: 2024-09-30
Rows: 135,528
Unique item names: 2,036
Columns of interest:

date: Transaction timestamp (irregular intervals, not every day or hour is available).
item_name: Name of the item sold (categorical).
quantity: Final sold quantity (target variable).
Other features: cost, rate, expiry_date, etc.



I receive new sales data every day and would like to build a model that can predict the demand for the next day, week, and month for a given item.
Specific Challenges:

Irregular time series: The timestamps in my data are not consistent (i.e., some days have missing entries). I plan to resample the data into daily intervals to handle this irregularity, but I'm concerned about the impact of this preprocessing step on model accuracy.
Multiple prediction horizons: I need to predict demand for different timeframes (next day, week, and month) using the same model.
Encoding categorical features: I’ve encoded item_name using label encoding. Is this approach appropriate, or is there a better method to encode this categorical feature for a time series problem?

Questions:

Is resampling the time series data into daily intervals the best approach to handle the irregular timestamps, or should I consider other techniques (e.g., interpolation)?
For predicting multiple time horizons (next day, week, and month), is an LSTM model suitable, or are there more effective models for this scenario?
What is the best way to handle categorical features like item_name in a time series context? Is label encoding sufficient, or would techniques like one-hot encoding or embedding layers be more effective?

